# How to Insert a document to a specific shard in Apache Solr Cloud Mode

Tags: solr, sharding

Is there a way we can add documents into a specific shard?

For example, documents type A will always get inserted into shard1 and document type B always go to shard2.

I have tried using custom router but it does not guaranty that different prefix will route to different shard.

PS. I am on Solr 5 using cloud mode.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm struggling with the same issue using Solr 5.1.0 in cloud mode.

Comment: @LandonC Turned out I live with random shards and multiple redundancy... 
if you find a solution, let me know :-)

Comment: With the help of some other folks, I have what I _believe_ is a solution. It works in a test scenario, that much I know. I'll post below.

Answer (score 3):

A caveat: I'm using SolrNet to access SolrCloud, and it doesn't integrate with ZooKeeper yet. For Java clients, this might be far easier.

Despite what I read [here](https://lucidworks.com/blog/solr-cloud-document-routing/) and [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Shards+and+Indexing+Data+in+SolrCloud) with regard to the `CompositeId Router`, I could never get it to work. What @jay helped me figure [out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604221/solrcloud-indexing-querying-without-a-smart-client) is a way to use "implicit" routing to achieve this. If you create your collection like this (leave out the `numShards` parameter):

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=myCol&maxShardsPerNode=2&router.name=implicit&shards=shard1,shard2&router.field=shard
```

then add a field to your `schema.xml` named "shard" (matching the `router.field` parameter), you can index to a specific shard simply by adding the `shard` field to the document being indexed and specifying the shard name. At query time, you can specify `shards` to search -- more [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Distributed+Requests) (I was able to simply specify the shard name w/o a specific address).

I haven't tested this in production yet, but have verified using multiple VirtualBox instances, with ZooKeeper, HAProxy, and several Solr nodes, and it's doing exactly what I expected. Corrections and comments welcome.